# Converting webpage to ReactJS ~ failed to compile "Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals"

Tags: reactjs, function, compiler-errors, web-deployment

I have some JS code that I need to make compatible with React Web.
I would appreciate some help as I am a little confused with what I need to do.

I get a failed to compile error when I make the following changes.

Currently the onclick function looks like this

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="openMenu(event, &#39;Starter&#39;);">
    <div className="w3-col s4 tablink w3-padding-large w3-hover-red">Starter</div></a>
```

Then I modify the onClick function to this, to attempt to get it to work

````
``` <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={(openMenu) => event, 'Pasta'}>
    <div class="w3-col s4 tablink w3-padding-large w3-hover-red">Salads</div> </a>
````

And the JS function looks like this:

```
    function openMenu(evt, menuName) {

            var i, x, tablinks;
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(menuName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-red";

        }
    document.getElementById("myLink").click();
```

If I make no changes the function dose not work and my goal is to get this function to work with react web.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, you mean the code in the first box doesn't work, and when you try changing it to the second example, you get an error about no-restricted-globals?

This is because you are using a "reserved" keyword (event). So when you change it from the HTML in the first one to a javascript evaluation, the compiler refuses to compile. This is to prevent misalignments of [global keywords.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object)

Your almost there with the second example:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={(openMenu) => event, 'Pasta'}>`

currently you have the function name in parens (openMenu) which isn't what you mean. The parens take the arguments you want to call the function with.

Something like

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={(event) => openMenu(event, 'Pasta')}>`

should work. The key thing I did was change how you are calling the function. If you have more questions about arrow functions, the React docs can be helpful. It just takes a while to get used to the new ES6 syntax.

Another way to solve this could use function currying:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={openMenu('Pasta')}>`

then the function could be rewritten as such:

```
   const openMenu = (menuName) => event => {   ...           
        event.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-red";
```

either of the ways presented will solve the problem for you (and many other ways as well).

Comment: Yes that is connect, first box dose not work and second box gives me that error. I will try your example and get back to you, thanks!